# API Hosted in Azure but Database is Hosted in our Network

Tags: c#, azure

Hi I was able to host an API application an Azure but unable to access the network of my database which is located in a different server under my network

I was wondering what things should I set up to make this happen

Comment: do you API application hosted on azure app service? Is your database in your on-premise network?

Comment: hi @nancy yes and yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you could enable the networking of app service to allow web app in the app service to access in a private network then connect the azure VNet and on-premise network via a site to site VPN gateway. You could get more details from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet).

However, in this case if you just want to access the database in another network, it's recommended to use Azure Hybrid Connections, it's a simple way without VPN gateway.

[Azure Hybrid Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections) enables you to connect your Azure App Services (including Azure Functions) to existing on-prem services/APIs. See [How to Add and Create Hybrid Connections in your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections#add-and-create-hybrid-connections-in-your-app) and more [reference](https://azuregems.io/azure-hybrid-connections/).